# Could not infer Generic type in completion handler

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to define a Generic type function but when I try to call this function I get `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Here is my code

```
func getBalance<T: BalanceListConstructable>(type: MarketType, completion:
 @escaping ((T) -> Void), failure: ((Error)  -> Void)?) where T : BalanceListConstructable  {    }
```

I then call this function using

```
getBalance(type: type, completion: { (result) in }) { (error) in}
```

but this give above compiler error. It's worth mentioning that `BalanceListConstructable` . I need this to be protocol since different types needs to call this function and therefore I cannot explicitly specify the type.

### Edit 1 Here is more detail about my scenario

Type: ListA and ListB both conforms to the protocol `BalanceListConstructable` which defines a custom initializer for both class.

I would like to make a network request and initialize the result of the completions handler based on the caller, so that if the call was made for the type `ListA`, the initializer of `ListA` is invoked etc

Here is my  implementation :

I fist define a protocol `BalanceListConstructable` to which both `ListA` and `ListB` should conform to.

```
protocol BalanceListConstructable {
init(json:JSON,header:[AnyHashable : Any]?) throws}
```

Then I implement my function like this

```
func getBalance<T>(type:MarketType,completion: @escaping ((T) -> 
Void),failure: ((Error) -> Void)?) where T:BalanceListConstructable
```

By doing this I was hopping to be able to access the initializer based on the caller so as example I need to initialize a `ListA` object like this

```
try T(json:JSON,header:[AnyHashable : Any]?)
```

T in this case can either be `ListA` or `ListB` But in all of my approach I could not make the complier to understand the `ListA` or `ListB` caller. is this even possible ?

Comment: What type should `result` be? The compiler doesn't know because you never told it.

Comment: result type is not clear and can change, It can be of type `ListA` or `ListB` but both types conform to `BalanceListConstructable`, I went this way because I exactly could not have a pre defined type for `result` any suggestions ?

Comment: Generics aren't the tool for the job then – you just want `completion:` to be of type `@escaping ((BalanceListConstructable) -> Void)`.

Comment: is there anyway for me to pass in Generic type here ? I need to access to the type later on and using protocol wont let me do that i.e I need to be able to do 
`T(json:response!,header:header)` which is the initializer of `ListA` or `ListB` depending which type was used

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you – either the caller decides the concrete type of `result` by way of generics, and then the callee can use this metatype to call your initialiser, or the callee decides the concrete type of `result`, in which case you just want to have `result` typed as `BalanceListConstructable`, as the caller cannot know what concrete type will be returned. Or are you saying that the caller has some metatype of type `BalanceListConstructable.Type`, which you want to pass to the function and get back a new instance of that type?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I update the question with more explanation of my problem. Maybe now is more clear

Comment: Oh so you do want generics – you just need to tell the compiler what type `result` is, as I was hinting at in my first comment, e.g `getBalance(type: type, completion: { (result: ListA) in }) { (error) in}`

Comment: Dear Sir, 
You just made someone's day :) . I wish the karma find it's way back to you